# flutter Async returns before end of end of function

Tags: flutter, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `initState` calling `getAllEventsAbout` and then continuing on to sorting, and then rendering the form.

However, the `getAllEventsAbout` doesn't complete all the way through.. It only does the async call, and then control is transferred back to `intiState` and then `getAllEventsAbout` continues afterwards.

So my form gets rendered blank - because the data hasn't been loaded into my List yet.

How do I ensure that the control will not be passed back until the end of the function?

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseDataApi.getAllEventsAbout(widget.event);

    eventAbout = Datasets.eventAbout;

    eventAbout.sort((a, b) {
      int compare1 = int.parse(a.sortOrder).compareTo(int.parse(b.sortOrder));
      if (compare1 == 0) {
        int compare2 = a.aboutTitle.compareTo(b.aboutTitle);
        if (compare2 == 0) {
          return a.aboutDescription.compareTo(b.aboutDescription);
        } else {
          return compare2;
        }
      } else {
        return compare1;
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

---

```
  static Future<List<EventAbout>> getAllEventsAbout(Event event) async {
    var collection = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('eventAbout')
        .where('eventId', isEqualTo: event.eventId)
        .get();

    //  ??????????????????????????????????
    // This is where the RETURN happens. 
    // Why isn't it finishing the entire function before returning?
    // ??????????????????????????????????
    
    Datasets.eventAbout.clear();

    for (var docSnapshot in collection.docs) {
      EventAbout e = EventAbout(
        eventId: docSnapshot.data()['eventId'],
        sortOrder: docSnapshot.data()['sortOrder'],
        aboutTitle: docSnapshot.data()['aboutTitle'],
        aboutDescription: docSnapshot.data()['aboutDescription'],
        action: docSnapshot.data().containsKey('action')
            ? docSnapshot.data()['action']
            : '',
      );

      Datasets.eventAbout.add(e);
    }

    print('eventAbout Successfully completed');
    return Datasets.eventAbout;
  }
```

Comment: did you try FutureBuilder?

 is your issue only happen in initState?

Comment: Of course `initState` didn't wait for `getAllEventsAbout` to complete; you must `await` `Future`s. `initState` should *not* depend on asynchronous operations; you instead should use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).